# How do I install this PECL package (PDO_4D) on PHP 7.1 on Red Hat 7?

Tags: php, pdo, redhat, pecl, 4d-database

I want to install the following PECL package (PDO-4D) on a Red Hat 7 server running PHP 7.1:

https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_4D

The documentation doesn't seem to explain how to do this, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDO_4D package available on PECL is not the most up-to-date.

You will find updated packages on Github, for example, [here](https://github.com/famsf/pecl-pdo-4d). The github repository has instructions for installing from source:

> ## BUILDING ON UNIX etc.
>
> To compile your new extension, you will have to execute the following steps:
>
> 1. $ phpize
> 2. $ ./configure --with-pdo_4d
> 3. $ make clean
> 4. $ make
> 5. $ make test
> 6. $ [sudo] make install

You could follow these same instructions for the source files downloaded from PECL.

---

An alternative approach for installing the PECL extension is to use [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.cli.php) like this:

```
pear install PECL/PDO_4D
```

You may need to make sure that pear is [setup](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php) first before running that.

---

There is also a [Technical Note](http://kb.4d.com/assetid=76265) that was published in 2011 regarding installing PDO_4D on Linux, although the document was written for Debian, not Red Hat.